# C# Process File Access Denied

Tags: c#, file, process, thread-safety, file-writing

While writing a file in a single thread application, I get the error

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

I open all writer objects in the using keyword. Although it is a single thread, I lock functions every time with ReaderWriterLockSlim and unlock them when I'm done. However, I am getting an error. Anything on your mind?

There are only these two functions that communicate with the file. One is appending, the other is cleaning the file.

```
 public void WriteToFileThreadSafe(string text, string fileName)
        {
            string path = ApplicationDirectory + "/" + fileName;
            _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(text);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public void ClearTextFile(string fileName)
        {
            string path = ApplicationDirectory + "/" + fileName;
            _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                using (FileStream sw = File.Create(path))
                {
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your lock implementation?

Comment: What process is locking your file? Can you ensure it is your program? https://superuser.com/q/117902

Comment: @GilvanJúnior see [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-5.0)

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your presented code. You don't need `sw.Close` in the using blocks but it's not an error. And you should use Path.Combine instead of string concatenation. You could make a try with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which processes are accessing the file, maybe antivirus or windows search indexer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers. I found problem. Program sends mail periodically. I didn't use using for mail and attachment instances. So, Garbage collector doesn't delete mail objects and program flow continue.. When any this function called program shutdown :D Thank you for your answers again. –